# Mobile rotation when keyboard open, disruptive the page

Tags: javascript, ios, css

I have a div form inside a site, which cover the site and take full screen size on mobile.

In the next scenario the div form is disruptive and not stretch to full screen:

Focus is on input field => The keyboard opened => rotate the mobile to landscape mode => result: half size div form.

Comment: *When the keyboard close, the div form stretch okay to full screen.
** Can use only vanilla javascript

the div form css:

```
  .div_form {
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    heigt: 100%;
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    }
```

Please help...

Comment: does it have to be position fixed? absolute might work better

Comment: The div must be in full screen size. Not in the site's size... Either way, it's not working....